# c# dotnetzip memorystream with zip file

Tags: c#, memorystream, dotnetzip

What I am trying to do in the code below is to open up a zip file from a memoryStream which has files within it that are created from memoryStream as well.

Note that I am using c# MVC as I have a return File...

memoryStream1 does have a length to it so not sure when I open up the archive.zip, it says

*Excel cannot open payload.xlsx because the file format or file extenion is not valid.
Verify that the fle has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches
the format of the file.*

The file extension is definitely xlsx so that can't be the problem. Am I going about this in the wrong way?

I have the following code:

```
    var memoryStream1 = new MemoryStream();
    gc.CreatePackage(memoryStream1);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
      zip.AddEntry("payload.xlsx", memoryStream1);
      zip.Save(memoryStream);
    }

    memoryStream.Seek(0, 0);
    return File(memoryStream, "application/octet-stream", "archive.zip");
```

Comment: So you're saying the zip is fine, just the excel inside isn't? Can you shouw us the `CreatePackage` method?

Comment: It is very extensive. I am using OpenXML SDK that creates it

Comment: Got it to work - needed  memoryStream1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);